# List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObjectExternal entry point

Tags: apex, method

I am fairly new to apex and I have this method where it updates a field on a record. all of the records that this method  receives comes from a batch

```
public static void updateOrderItemReturnedSerialNumber(List<OrderItem> newOrderItemList, Map<Id, OrderItem> oldOrderItemMap) {
    OrderItemDAI itemDAO = (OrderItemDAI) DAOFactory.getDAO(OrderItem.SObjectType);
    
    Set<Id> originalOrderItemId = new Set<Id>();
    List<OrderItem> returnedReplacementOrderItemToUpdateList = new List<OrderItem>();
    List<OrderItem> orderItemToUpdateList = new List<OrderItem>();
    
    //Get all the Order Item that has Returned_Serial Number and Status is Cancelled
    for(OrderItem item : newOrderItemList) {
        if (item.Status__c == ConstantsOrder.ORDER_STATUS_CANCELLED && oldOrderItemMap.get(item.Id).Status__c!= item.Status__c && item.Returned_Serial_Number__c != null && (item.RecordType__c == ConstantsGlobal.SS_ORDER_RETURN_RT_ID || item.RecordType__c == ConstantsGlobal.SS_REPLACEMENT_RT_ID)) {
            originalOrderItemId.add(item.OriginalOrderItem__c);
            returnedReplacementOrderItemToUpdateList.add(item);
        }
    }
    System.debug('originalOrderItemId: '+ originalOrderItemId);
    System.debug('returnedReplacementOrderItemToUpdateList: '+ returnedReplacementOrderItemToUpdateList);
    
    if (returnedReplacementOrderItemToUpdateList.isEmpty() && originalOrderItemId.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    
    
    //Gets the Original Order Item Map
    Map<Id,OrderItem> originalOrderItemMap = new Map<Id,OrderItem> (itemDAO.getRecordsByIds(originalOrderItemId));
    System.debug('originalOrderItemMap1: '+ originalOrderItemMap);
    
    //To populate Original Order Item Serial Number
    for(OrderItem returnOrderItem : returnedReplacementOrderItemToUpdateList){
        
        System.debug('@@@@@@@returnOrderItem: '+ returnOrderItem);
        
        if(originalOrderItemMap.get(returnOrderItem.OriginalOrderItem__c).Serial_Number__c != null){//&& originalOrderItemMap.get(returnOrderItem.OriginalOrderItem__c).Serial_Number__c.contains(';')
            
            Set<String> serialNumber = new Set<String>(originalOrderItemMap.get(returnOrderItem.OriginalOrderItem__c).Serial_Number__c.split(';'));
            serialNumber.add(returnOrderItem.Returned_Serial_Number__c);
            originalOrderItemMap.get(returnOrderItem.OriginalOrderItem__c).Serial_Number__c = String.join( new List<String>(serialNumber), ';' );
            returnOrderItem.Returned_Serial_Number__c = null;
            System.debug('serialNumber: '+ serialNumber);
            System.debug('originalOrderMap.get(returnOrderItem.OriginalOrderItem__c).Serial_Number__c: '+ originalOrderItemMap.get(returnOrderItem.OriginalOrderItem__c).Serial_Number__c);
        }else{
            returnOrderItem.Returned_Serial_Number__c = null;
            originalOrderItemMap.get(returnOrderItem.OriginalOrderItem__c).Serial_Number__c = oldOrderItemMap.get(returnOrderItem.Id).Returned_Serial_Number__c;
        }
        orderItemToUpdateList.add(originalOrderItemMap.values());
        System.debug('originalOrderItemMap2: '+ originalOrderItemMap);
    }
    
    if (!orderItemToUpdateList.isEmpty()) {
        itemDAO.updateRecords(orderItemToUpdateList, true);
    }        
}
```

This method produces the error List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObjectExternal entry point when updating more than 1 record and I believe this condition is where the error occurs `if(originalOrderItemMap.get(returnOrderItem.OriginalOrderItem__c).Serial_Number__c != null)`

Is there a way to properly address this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Could you please include the exact error message, and if it includes a line number? Have you tried debugging this process as well with debug logs enabled? Could you please [edit] your question to add more details.